# More than 1 song playing in Media Player at same time

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I am new to Android programming and I am trying to make a simple Media Player app which extracts songs from the user's SD Card and enables the user to play the songs. The problem I face is that while a song is playing, if the user clicks on some other song, that song also starts playing.

I searched for the solution and used release() but the problem persists.

I would appreciate any help given!

Relevant code:

```
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{

NotificationManager nm;
Notification n;

private Button play, forward, backward, next, prev, repeat, shuffle;
private ImageButton playlist;
private SeekBar sb;
private TextView songTitle, currDur, totDur;

private MediaPlayer mp;
private SongManager sManager;
private Utilities utils;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private int seekForwardTime = 5000;
private int seekBackwardTime = 5000;
private boolean isShuffle = false;
private boolean isRepeat = false;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> songList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

int songIndex;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);

    if(mp!=null)
    {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp=null;
    }
    init_player();
    songIndex = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("songIndex");

    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    n = new Notification(R.drawable.notif,"Alert",System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent j = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    j.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pp= PendingIntent.getActivity(Player.this, 0, j, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContentIntent(pp);
    builder.setTicker(songList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle"));
    builder.setContentTitle("Playing");
    builder.setContentText(songList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle"));
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    builder.setNumber(100);
    builder.build();

    n = builder.getNotification();
    nm.notify(0, n);

    playSong(songIndex);
 //Various Button Click Listeners
}
protected void init_player() {

    play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    forward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
    backward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    repeat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
    shuffle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
    playlist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_playlist);

    sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
    songTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songName);
    currDur = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
    totDur = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    sManager = new SongManager(Player.this);
    utils = new Utilities();

    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);

    songList = sManager.getPlaylist(0);
}
protected void playSong(int songIndex)
{
    try {

        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();

        songTitle.setText(songList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle"));
        play.setText("PAUSE");
        sb.setProgress(0);
        sb.setMax(100);
        updateProgressBar();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IllegalStateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note : Player class gets called by the MainActivity and receives the integer songIndex (reresenting the index of song in the ArrayList)

Comment: what code do you use when clicks on song that you want to play?

Comment: This code seems to be OK, you must be making mistake on previous screen like this.  You may be creating multiple instant of Player activity. And passing URL using intent `songIndex` So each time when you click on row on previous screen, your app creates new Instance of Player activity. Try this in `AndroidManifeast.xml`
`<activity ..
      android:launchMode= "singleInstance" />`

Comment: @MAC, I inserted that line in the Player Activity in the manifest file...It solved the problem of more than 1 song playing simultaneously. But, now the problem is that when the user clicks on some song when some song is already playing, that song won't start and the previous one will keep on playing. So now, there is no freedom for the user. Can you suggest something so that when the user clicks on some other song, that song will start and the previous one will stop?   Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin, when the user clicks on a song in the MainActivity (ListView), the Player activity gets invoked using an Intent and the songIndex gets passed to the Player activity.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this in playSong() method**

```
if (mp.isPlaying()) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.relase();
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
}
```

Comment: Android documentation clearly states that the player should be released in the onStop() method of the activity...

Comment: I tried this code before I posted the question and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have several media player instances at the same time? You should check that.

You have to release your media player inside the onStop() method of your activity like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();  // Always call the superclass method first

mediaPlayer.release();
mediaPlayer = null;
}
```

From the official documentation:

```
As an example, consider the problems that could happen if you forgot to release the MediaPlayer when your activity is stopped, but create a new one when the activity starts again. 
As you may know, when the user changes the screen orientation (or changes the device configuration in another way), the system handles that by restarting the activity (by default), 
so you might quickly consume all of the system resources as the user rotates the device back and forth between portrait and landscape, 
because at each orientation change, you create a new MediaPlayer that you never release.
```

Having too many player instances at the same time, you will have errors like OutOfMemory or *too many open files*.

Btw. you should not use the constructor directly but instantiate the media player using the create() method as described here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm

Comment: Please state if using overriding onStop() like this helped :)

Comment: I used the onStop() to release the MediaPlayer resources and to make it null. It caused the app to crash when I clicked on a song to play it.

Comment: I mean it crashed when I clicked on the playlist image button to go back to the MainActivity.

Comment: What is the exact cause of the crash? Can you post it here?